# Can a Debian package's Priority field be used for selection for install?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

In a Debian package's control file, there is a [`Priority` field](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-priorities) which can be set to one of:

- `required`
- `important`
- `standard`
- `optional`
- `extra`

APT pinning can be used to specify priorities for packages from different sources but this setting is local to the computer which is actually updating and not distributed via the repository.

Can the package's priority be used by APT for selection for install? E.g. can you pass a parameter to `apt-get dist-upgrade` to only upgrade required packages?

If not, what is this field used for? Does it link in with the APT pinning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Policy Manual link you provided reads:

> This information is used by the Debian package management tools to separate high-priority packages from less-important packages.

This means several things:

- the package management tools require extra confirmation before removing *required* packages,
- `aptitude` lets you search or limit the display based on priority (the latter makes it possible to operate on packages based on priority, try <kbd>l</kbd> then type `?priority(required)` for example),
- other package managers probably have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Debian minimal install is essential + required + important + some hardware dependent.

Try

```
aptitude --disable-columns --display-format %p search '?and(?installed, ?priority(required))'
```

to list installed and required packages and pipe them into apt

```
| xargs apt install
```

If an update is available it will be installed.

See the [Search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) and my [Debian OS image normalization](https://github.com/szepeviktor/debian-server-tools/blob/master/debian-setup/debian-image-normalize.sh) script.

Comment: If you have packages removed but not purged add `$not(?config-files)`